# Complete the Hangman Game - BBC R1

Tags: password

Currently on BBC Radio 1, one of the presenters is stuck in an escape room, and needs the listeners' help to break out.

One of the puzzles is the following:

[image]

Can the PSE community help?

You can watch the livestream of the escape room here:
https://www.bbc.co.uk/events/ezzcd4/live/cfz6v2

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's from an ongoing competition.

Comment: @JonMarkPerry It's not a competition, it is ongoing but no one can win anything (as far as I'm aware)

Comment: @AHKieran In this case it's better to be safe and wait a few hours than be sorry. I'm sure people can contribute on twitter if needed anyway.

Comment: One wonders why the player didn't choose some more likely candidate letters like E, A, and T,...? I mean FVYWZQ???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quoting Aaron Lowman on Twitter:

> **Artists with a song *related to stars*:**
>
>  1. Ellie Goulding — *Starry Eyed*
>  2. Tinie Tempah — *Written in the Stars*
>  3. Kendrick Lamar — *All the Stars*
>  4. Coldplay — *Sky Full of Stars*
>  5. OneRepublic — *Counting Stars*
>  6. Lady Gaga — *A Star is Born*